# Error caused by trying to find index of something that isnt in list anymore

Tags: python, pygame

I'm a student working with python to make a simple game. Whenever the last character dies I get `builtins.ValueError: (A health value) is not in list`
I am trying to find the lowest health in a list of characters and subtract a damage from their health. 
The error occurs at `character_health_list.index(lowest_health)` in my code.

```
character_health_list = [character_list[0].health, 
                         character_list[1].health,
                         character_list[2].health, 
                         character_list[3].health]

for i in range(len(character_list)):     
    if character_list[i].health > 0:
        lowest_health = min(i for i in character_health_list if i > 0)    

# Damage that the enemy does
for i in range(len(enemy_list)):
    lowest_health_char = character_health_list.index(lowest_health)
```

Comment: It might not be wise to use `i` as the index within your `min` generator.

The cause of the issue could be that the `i` placed in that list is from the scope of the parent `for` loop rather than where you expect.

Comment: Also, if the list is empty, then `lowest_health` will be `None` (or whatever you initialised it with before). In that case `.index` will fail.

Comment: It's **probably** a safe bet that `i` isn't the issue, seeing as `i` isn't really used past the `if` statement. However, It would be neat to know what `lowest_health` is, why you need to do `if i > 0` and what all the values are in general. And what library are you using that's generating `(A health value) is not in list`? That's not a standard error from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>`lowest_health` is not set to the index of the character with the lowest health, it is set to the value of the character's health.</strike> Currently, your loop setup is a bit inefficient, as it finds the lowest value and then works backward to find the index of the character with the lowest value. It would probably be easier to rewrite it to something like this:

```
# index of character with lowest health
lowest_health = 0

for i in range(len(character_list)):
    # check that health is greater than 0 and less than the current minimum
    if (character_health_list[i] > 0 and
        character_health_list[i] < character_health_list[lowest_health]):
        lowest_health = i
```

Edit: I didn't see the `.index` call

Answer (score 0):

So here's the thing, I'm not sure if your character list has only these 4 elements as you mentioned. So if I take that your character health list has only 4 elements, it can be possible that when you're iterating over the whole `character_list` there are more than these 4 elements and the `health` property from one of those extra elements are being counted as `lowest_health`

Assuming that a character is dead when their health is 0, you need to get the lowest health from the alive ones, you can do it in a better way like this

```py
# get all the health
character_health_list = [character.health for character in character_list if character.health > 0]

# get the lowest health from character_list
lowest_health = min(health for health in character_health_list)

# now get the index
health_index = character_health_list.index(lowest_health)
```